# How to get a complicated PagedList using SS3

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

In my demo, I have three table in database, TProduct, TCategory and TProductCategoryMap.

> TProduct (ProductId int PK, OtherFields)
>   TCategory (CategoryId int PK, OtherFields)
>   TMap (ProductId int PK, CategoryId int PK)

Now, I need to get a PagedList of Products with specific categoryid.

Here is my code:

```
  IQueryable<Product> products = from product in _repo.All<TProduct>()
                                 join map in _repo.All<TMap>() on product.ProductId equals map.ProductId
                                 where map.CategoryId == specificCagetoryId
                                 select product;
```

If I stop here and return products, everything is ok.
But If I return a pagedlist like this:

```
   return new PagedList<TProduct>(products, pageIndex, pageSize);
```

the generated sql text will cause a syntax error "The ranking function "ROW_NUMBER" must have an ORDER BY clause. "

Do I use the wrong linq expression? Then how can I get a correct result?

Give me some advice, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the current version: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issuesearch?state=open&q=PagedList#issue/35

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this bug as of... right now! Will push the next release sometime today.

Comment: What Version is this fix found in or do you need to download the source